# Reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, mono, omnisharp

I try to open a Unity3D project with VSCode under Linux (Ubuntu 18.10). The omnisharp extension doesn't load the project, saying assemblies were not found.

It may seems very stupide, but i'm not really used to .Net yet, and i have been stuck with this error for quite some days now.
I have been trying re-installing dotnet (even using the snap package), mono, vscode and the omnisharp extension.

So any help is welcome ! :)

Unity version : 2018.3.1f1

**Logs :**

**dotnet -- info**

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.103
 Commit:    8edbc2570a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.10
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.10-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.103/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.1
  Commit:  878dd11e62

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.103 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

**mono --version**

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (Debian 4.6.2.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

**The full log error :**

```
    Starting OmniSharp server at 1/26/2019, 7:13:55 PM
    Target: /home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/TestProject.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/run
    PID: 30136

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 18.10 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 15.0 - "/home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 15.0 - "/home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            CscToolPath = /home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Roslyn
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin
            TargetFrameworkRootPath = /usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Project system 'OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem' is disabled in the configuration.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in '/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/TestProject.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpWorkspaceOptionsProvider
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject' on host 30056.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/home/eyap/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1195,5): Error: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attemped to update project that is not loaded: /home/eyap/Projects/Unity/TestProject/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

Comment: For future viewers : I decided to keep the accepted answer as that was the one that made it work for me at the time. However, please take a look at the highest voted answer for a more recent solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same issue but on OSX. Installing latest version of Mono cleared up the missing .net v4.7.1 framework references.

I installed Mono V5.18.0 from https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable

### Update: See comment below regarding global omnisharp setting

Comment: That might be it ! I previously installed mono just as they describe on their website, but i wrongly assumed that it was up-to-date. But it's not the case for Ubuntu 18.10 (it's still in 4.6).... I will try that tomorrow, thanks a lot !

Comment: This worked for me. I guess the last Unity update I installed bumped the required version number up past what the Ubuntu Apt sources provide.

Comment: '''sudo apt upgrade mono-devel'''. The current latest version is 6.10

Comment: I have the latest Mono and I'm still getting this problem.

Comment: Can confirm this work on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 47):

Tried the steps mentioned here, did not resolve the error. Had to do change the `omnisharp.useGlobalMono` option to `always`. This worked for `C# extension for VS Code=1.23.2`.

Source: [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/il36tn/vscode_with_unity_on_linux/g3zjp5j?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> Your error output tells me that you're using the official C# extension
> for VS Code. The latest version of said extension, 1.23.2, has this to
> say in its changelog:
>
> ```
> For Mono-based development (e.g. Unity) that requires full .NET framework, you need to set "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always". This
> ```
>
> is needed until Mono upgrades their bundled MSBuild version
>
> The default setting, auto, does not work. Switch it to always and
> restart the extension. Alternatively you could downgrade to 1.23.1.

Comment: This worked for me on VSCode `1.49.1`, Unity `2020.1.6f1`, and Mono `6.10.0 Stable` without modifying PATH or any environment variables

Comment: Finally I got my Intellisense working like a charm after this step. Definitely made my day, thanks!!

Comment: You are my hero, this saved my evening!

Comment: Here I am, one year and a half later, finding this error again. This time, this solution worked great for me ! Thanks :)

Comment: This was it for me too!

Comment: It worked for me as well! But, before I had to make sure that my `mono`, which was installed with `brew` was linked.

Comment: On a Mac -> Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> type "use global mono", update config to always.

Comment: Thanks Man, this saved me from my ordeal on Ubuntu 20.04 with VSCode 1.51.1

Comment: This didn't resolve it for me on Windows 10, I still get "The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found." :(

Comment: @Paresh you are the MVP

Comment: On Arch linux I also had to add mono-msbuild and mono-msbuild-sdkresolver packages besides mono.

Answer (score 27):

I was in the same situation and I found a workaround here : https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2728

You have to `export FrameworkPathOverride=/lib/mono/4.5` and the .NETFramework will be found.

Comment: thanks, for this answer. worked for me on macOS. added that variable to my shell config.

Comment: where do you type that export line? how does Unity or VS Code know how to find that export?

Comment: This worked for me: `export FrameworkPathOverride=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current`

Comment: That's the problem exactly, You saved my day, Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and here is how I fixed it.

1. Download the latest stable Mono from [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) and install.
2. Add FrameworkPathOverride to the .bash_profile

```
export FrameworkPathOverride=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
```

Restart VSCode and It works.

Answer (score 4):

1. In linux mint 18.3 Sylvia (ubuntu 16.04) install mono-devel like https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin.
2. Then execute in terminal `export FrameworkPathOverride=/etc/mono/4.5`
3. Open vs code and works.

Comment: Installing latest `mono` didn't help me. But the export fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Linux mint 18.3 Sylvia (Ubuntu 16.04) install mono-devel like https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin.
Then execute in terminal

```
export FrameworkPathOverride=/etc/mono/4.5
```

Open VScode and it works.This is what worked for me on a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 10 users out there:

---

If you're still encountering this Omnisharp error:

```
The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found.
```

1. Close VS Code if it's already open
2. Download and Install **.NETFramework 4.7.1 Developer Pack**
   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net471
   (VS Code might suggest newer versions but as of 3/25/2022 they don't work)
3. Reopen the Unity Project in VS Code

---

The steps above should resolve the issue, but if you're still having problems (e.g., Intellisense not working properly), try adjusting your Unity settings:

1. Open your Unity project, click **Edit** > **Project Settings...** > **Player** > **Other Settings** > **API Compatibility Level** (Under Configuration)
2. Change API Compatibility Level to `.NET 4.x`
3. Restart Unity & VS Code

Answer (score 0):

After one day researching whats going wrong. with .NETFRAMEWORK 4.7 on ubuntu and unity. I solved this by changing omnisharp:useglobalmenu to always inside VSCODE setting. here is a solution link I found https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3613#issuecomment-677451385

Answer (score 0):

On newer OmniSharp versions (for .NET 6 development) the "**Omnisharp: Use modern Net**" option needs to be disabled.
Maybe change it for the local workspace only in order to keep your non-unity .NET core projects unaffected.

*VS Code*: **File > Preferences > Settings (optional: > Workspace tab) > Omnisharp: Use modern net**

Alternatively change the .vscode/settings.json file, inside either your home folder (global setting) or the project workspace (local setting).

*.vscode/settings.json*: `{ [...] "omnisharp.useModernNet": false, [...] }`