# Cant get Intellisense to work with Unity, using VSCode, under Ubuntu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am building a Unity3d project under Ubuntu 19.10, and I cannot get Visual Studio Code to show me Intellisense. I get this error output:

https://hastebin.com/arisekehih.txt

There is a line that reads

> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application

But .NET Framework is only for Windows.

I have Visual Studio Code 1.43 installed, with the extension C# (ms-dotnettools.csharp). I installed it using the .deb package on the website.

I followed [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) and set it up as the default editor:

[image]

What could I do?

Comment: Have you tried installing OmniSharp extension to VSCode?

Comment: Can you please give me the url/id of that extension?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after change `omnisharp.useGlobalMono` on vs code settings to `always`.

I use Unity3d 2020, Ubuntu 20.04, vs code 1.49.2, and intellisense is work.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763959/11445944) from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/il36tn/vscode_with_unity_on_linux/g3zjp5j?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)