# Mono on linux: Metadata file '/mscorlib.dll' could not be found

Tags: .net, linux, dll, mono

I got lots of `assembly not found` errors when compiling the [Spire project](https://github.com/eth-sri/Spire) via `dotnet build` so I installed the package **mono-complete** as stated [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu) and also exported the variable `FrameworkPathOverride=/lib/mono/4.5` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070707/11970791).Overriding the framework path solved the first `assembly not found` problems but generated new ones:

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '/mscorlib.dll' could not be found [blah-blah-blah.csproj]
```

The file `mscorelib.dll` is in `/usr/lib/mono/4.5/` and is not a symlink but I don't know why it cannot find that.Also if I change `FrameworkPathOverride=/lib/mono/4.5` to `FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5` that error disappears and these errors show up:

```
Spire.cs(19,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Options' does not exist in the namespace 'Mono' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
Synthesize.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
```

I've installed both `Z3` and `Mono.Options` before,so the absence of those is not the problem.

BTW I use ubuntu 18.04.

I have little experience using .NET and mono so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
If I run the `build.sh` script , I get:

```
WARNING: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
Unable to find version '5.3.0.1' of package 'Mono.Options'.
./build.sh: line 4: msbuild: command not found
```

Comment: Read its build shell script please. It requires Mono, not .NET Core, so you cannot use ˋdotnet build`.

Comment: @LexLi Running ```xbuild``` also throws errors such as ```The type `System.IO.TextWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.IO```.But ```System.IO``` is already installed by nuget,but is not present in the ```/usr/lib/mono/4.5/``` directory.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the output when you run `build.sh`. Don't invent your own steps when you have little idea what you are doing.

Comment: @LexLi Added the output.

Comment: That output indicates a lot of issues. 1) You don't have the latest Mono, so you must upgrade https://www.mono-project.com/download/preview/#download-lin-ubuntu 2) NuGet restore seems to fail, which prevents the actual references from being downloaded. Once you have the latest Mono installed, run `build.sh` again and post its output.